# Connecting PWM computer fan to transistor and adjustable resistor

Tags: voltage

Edit: Please do not change the circuit after the circuit has been discussed and answered. Thank-you. --MathKeepsMeBusy

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRpuE3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm making a jet car, and I'm making the electronics for it. Is it safe to control the speed of the PWM fan by controlling the voltage across the positive and negative leads with a transistor connected to an adjustable resistor? The adjustable resistor is the throttle lever in my car.

Comment: Please provide a circuit diagram (with the tool) of what you intend to do and the model of fan

Comment: yes, my car is light, so it moves.

Comment: sweet .........

Comment: There are voltage-controlled fans. Maybe those would fit your use-case better...

Answer (score 2):

What you show will be basically 'all on' or 'all off'. It won't properly regulate the fan speed. Even if you were able to make it work, it would be hugely inefficient. (It could be made to work using a current mirror technique, but this would destroy that poor 2n3904 in short order.)

You've probably seen circuits like that using an NPN or a FET on the low side. It's the common way to control a 2-wire fan (or for that matter, any DC motor) very cheaply. What you're missing is that these circuits use a *PWM signal* to control the transistor, essentially 'chopping' the current to reduce the power delivered to the fan. These work without killing the transistor because the transistor is either fully-on (saturated) or fully off, so it isn't shedding much power.

Whether PWM-chopping the power works or not depends on how tolerant the brushless DC (BLDC) fan motor is of having a chopped voltage: some are ok with it, some fail.

Fortunately, you have a solution literally in-hand. Intel, in their infinite wisdom, specified that their standard platforms use a *4-wire-fan*, which includes a separate PWM input. This input chops the coil driver voltage, but keeps the BLDC controller powered up, so it works perfectly over a wide range of PWM frequencies and duty cycles.

Lucky for the rest of us not making PCs, Intel's benevolence ensures a cheap and available supply of these easy-to-use 4-wire fans.

You've got a 4-wire PWM fan. Awesome, you're one step ahead of the game. So make a PWM signal and drive the fan's PWM input. This takes advantage of the fan's built-in chopping circuit to regulate the fan speed, giving you full control from 0 to 100% fan speed.

You can make a PWM signal with the venerable 555 timer IC. Here's an example: https://www.electroschematics.com/pulse-generator-with-555/

And another: https://colourtvservicebbsr.blogspot.com/2016/04/pwm-speed-motor-controller-by-ic-555.html

The chop frequency for PC fans is normally 25KHz, but you can use lower frequencies (like 100-300 Hz) if you wish if you don't mind about hearing the 'chop' noise from the fan.

Later, you could enhance your design using an R/C proportional control, which uses PWM to control servos.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably feasible, but it wouldn't be PWM.  PWM stands for "Pulse Width Modulation," and it's used to vary the average voltage indirectly by switching the applied voltage on and off repeatedly, and varying the amount of time it's on.

If you voltage controlled the motor as you propose, it would be far less efficient and would require your transistor to dissipate a lot of power.  Depending on the motor design, it's also likely to put strains on the motor at different voltages that it's not designed for.

You can look for 555-based PWM controllers, or alternatively some microcontrollers have PWM peripherals.

Comment: I edited the post above/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use it for anything critical.  There's no datasheet I can find for that specific model but if it has tachometer and PWM, chances are there are other features such as auto-restart and stall protection that could fail to operate correctly if supplied with an out-of-spec voltage.  In my experience, operating DC fans outside their voltage range only produces a narrow band of usable control before hitting stall territory but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit you propose does not smoothly turn on the transistor. Over most of the range of the throttle lever, a small change in resistance will have little effect on the current through the motor. In addition, the current through the base will likely be excessive for that transistor. You need different resistance values and a resistor between your throttle resistor and the transistor base.

Finally, your transistor will dissipate a great deal of heat, even if the biasing is corrected. Not an efficient way to control a motor, and probably will destroy transistor unless motor is tiny.

When the wiper of the potentiometer is at "full throttle", the voltage on the wiper will be 12V. The transistor will not survive this.

Also, although I was unable to find a datasheet for the kdb04505ha, I have seen it advertised as 5V 0.29A. If it really is a 5V fan, it will probably be damaged if supplied with 12V.

Comment: I edited the post. Are these correct resistance values? When the thrust lever is at the bottom the fan should be turning at idle speed, and when it's at the top, it should run at full speed.

Comment: When the resistor wiper is "at the bottom", the voltage on the wiper will be 0. The transistor will be off. The transistor will start to turn on significantly when the wiper/base voltage is 0.6V. Once the wiper voltage reaches around 0.7V or at most 0.75V, the transistor will saturate. Turning the wiper higher will increase base current, but not increase collector current significantly. It is unlikely that the transistor will survive the wiper being "at the top", as the base voltage would then be 12V, far beyond what a BJT will survive. This is not the way to control a motor.

Comment: At the top, the resistor value is 100 ohms.

Comment: Even if true, the transistor will probably be destroyed. Back of the envelope calculation, 12V-0.7V \$\approx\$ 11V. 11V/100\$\Omega\$ = 110mA. 110mA x 0.7V = 770mW. That is just the power dissipated by the base current. Add to that the power from the collector current, and you have magic smoke.

Comment: You should not substantially edit a question after it has been discussed and answered. Ask a new question. Although I have not seen a datasheet for the kdb04505ha, I have seen it advertised at 5V and 0.29 A. With your latest edit, with full throttle, you will have 12V on your 5V fan. Not good. Also, At bottom throttle, you will have 12V/2.5K = 4.8mA. Not likely to cause a budge.