# Case fan making humming noise when used with potentiometer

Tags: voltage, fan

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5JUYm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I turn on the circuit above, when the potentiometer is not at minimum or full speed, the fan makes a high-pitched whining sound, but the speed still changes. How do I prevent the whining?

Comment: A resistor in series with the supply could be upsetting the electronics in the fan. Have you tried decoupling the supply for the fan by connecting a 100uF (or higher value) 16 V capacitor in parallel with the GND and VCC of the fan?

Comment: I guess you should try a different power supply (different manufacturer). What is the power supply you are using? I guess it has a ripple with a frequency which is the same frequency your fan oscillates (since it has a coil), and at a specific Voltage the ripple becomes big enough to make a big sound.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios I am using a 6v battery to power the case fan.

Comment: @ChristiandisVasileios Actually I'm using 4 AA batteries to power it.

Comment: Hm the batteries shouldn't create any noise. Can you post a picture of your whole setup? Also, is your fan new or it is a old fan?

Comment: you can prevent the whining by using the fan in a way it was designed, not forcing a mode of operation that it was not designed for

Comment: if you use 3 AA cells to get 4.5V does the sfan still whine?

Comment: @Jasen No, it whines only when the speed is adjusted with a potentiometer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The fan. Image source: [PChub](https://www.pchub.com/).*

This type of fan does not control a simple brushed DC motor. Instead, they contain a BLDC (BrushLess DC) motor and drive electronics.

[image]

*Figure 2. A typical BLDC fan driver circuit. Image source: [EE web](https://www.eeweb.com/bldc-sinusoidal-fan-motor-driver/).*

By powering the fan through a resistance you are probably charging up some internal capacitance and the driver chip turns on at some internal voltage threshold. It in turn starts up the motor which will promptly discharge the internal energy store, stop the motor and the cycle starts again.

Instead you should be powering the fan at the rated voltage and using the PWM input to control the speed.

[image]

*Figure 3. PWM signal transitioning from high pulse width (75%) to low (25%) and back again should result in 75% and 25% of full speed. Image source: [LEDnique.com](http://lednique.com/power-supplies/dimmable-mains-psu-control/).*

You'll find plenty of PWM control examples on a web search.

Comment: What did you find in your web search as recommended in the last line of my answer?

Comment: @ssr215 - You asked: "*how do I do PWM with potentiometer speed control?*". You were already pointed at a couple of simple PWM controllers, in an answer to one of your previous questions 2 days ago on the same topic: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/553913/connecting-pwm-computer-fan-to-transistor-and-adjustable-resistor

Comment: Sorry, @ssr215, but this isn't a "gimme the codz" kind of site. You do your research and we'll help you when you get stuck.

Comment: @ssr215 - Regarding: "*I want the schematic*" Did you follow the link I included in my previous comment, and read the answers to that earlier question of yours? :-) What did you find, **exactly**?

Comment: this fan does not have a PWM input.

Comment: @Jasen I have the 4 wire model